# Brownian tree algorithm

Tags: algorithm

i have doubt with the BTA.

1. Place one particle somewhere in the area.
2. Place a second particle also in a random position.
3. Start moving the second particle until it meets the first particle or any other belonging to the tree.

In the "movement" the particle leaves another behind on each step it makes, forming a "path" or the particle is fixed just when meets a particle belonging to the tree or the initial particle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Judging by the pictures in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_tree) on brownian trees, during the movement phase the particle does *not* leave a trail of pixels behind it. If it did leave a trail, I would expect to see branches that cross over themselves (Like the images in [Brownian Motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion), for example)

This explains why the algorithm took hours or days to run in the nineties - a particle may wander around for a long time before hitting the seed, and only grow the tree by a single pixel.